# convert a sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert the following mysql query to linq. However I do not have past experience working with joins in linq. Could I get some tips on how I can approach this.

```sql
SELECT db.jm_job.jobID
     , sum(MaterialPrice+LaborPrice+ExpensePrice) * db.jm_workorderdetail.quantity 
FROM db.jm_workorderdetail 
     left join db.jm_workorder 
         on db.jm_workorderdetail.WorkOrderID=db.jm_workorder.WorkOrderID
     left join db.jm_job 
         on db.jm_job.JobID=db.jm_workorder.JobID
group by db.jm_job.jobID
```

Comment: Not valid SQL to begin with

Comment: @RobertMcKee I think its valid.unless I missed something

Comment: Your select list includes `* db.jm_workorderdetail.quantity`

Comment: I am running the query right now in mysql and it working.

Comment: Perhaps there is some esoteric syntax that I'm not aware of, but it appears that you are trying to give the output column of `sum(MaterialPrice+LaborPrice+ExpensePrice)` a name of `*`, and then I have no idea what it would do with `db.jm_workorderdetail.quantity`.  Missing comma perhaps?

Comment: Yes i am multiplying the sum of those columns with the quantity column

Comment: Ouch.  Boy did I read that wrong.

Comment: It is selecting jobID and then next column is the sum of material price, labor price, expense price multiplied with the workorder.quantity column.

Comment: Please never just drop SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts.

Comment: do you see how much easier that is? please format a tiny bit...

Answer (score 1):

Inner Joins in LINQ are simple enough, but a left join is a bit trickier, involving temporary LINQ variables.

Obviously, you have the MSDN documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Another SO post on the same topic: [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

And a bunch of examples of how JOINS work in LINQ: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin

I'll leave the SELECT and WHERE block for you to figure out, but here is roughly how your joins should end up looking:

```
var results = from wod in db.jm_workorderdetail
from wo in db.jm_workorder.Where(w => w.WorkOrderID == wod.WorkOrderID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from job in db.jm_job.Where(j => j.JobID == wo.JobID).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {SELECT LOGIC GOES HERE}
```

The most important part here is the .DefaultIfEmpty() clause as that is what creates the 'left join' behavior of returning a null if the WHERE doesn't work

This also leaves out the group by clause, you can find some good resources on that by just googling 'LINQ Group By'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT db.jm_job.jobID, 
       sum( MaterialPrice + LaborPrice + ExpensePrice) * db.jm_workorderdetail.quantity 

  FROM db.jm_workorderdetail 

  LEFT JOIN db.jm_workorder 
    ON db.jm_workorderdetail.WorkOrderID = db.jm_workorder.WorkOrderID

  LEFT JOIN db.jm_job on db.jm_job.JobID=db.jm_workorder.JobID
  GROUP BY db.jm_job.jobID
```

Think it's something like this:

```
from detail in db.jm_workorderdetail

join wo in db.jm_workorder 
  on db.jm_workorderdetail.WorkOrderID equals db.jm_workorder.WorkOrderID

join job in db.jm_job 
  on db.jm_job.JobID equals db.jm_workorder.JobID

group jm_job by job.jobId into grp

select new 
{ 
    jobId = grp.key,
    something = (MaterialPrice + LaborPrice  + ExpensePrice) * wo.jm_workorderdetail.quantity
}
```

```

Comment: This provides an INNER JOIN, not the left join that the asker requested.

Comment: I suppose you are correct, but looking at the output, that is probably what he really wanted.  I doubt you'd really want a null jobid with a total of all the unassigned workorderdetails.